# How do I place blocks without breaking existing ones?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on single player creative mode.

When I try and place down a block, all it does is break existing blocks. So, how do I place down a block without doing this?

Comment: Are you clicking the left or right mousebutton... Left breaks a block right places a block.

Answer (score 18):

Try clicking the other mouse button.

Comment: @FTFTFT If this answer has helped you, mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark. You'll get some reputation points!

Comment: @fredley If this answer indeed helped out I will fall out of my chair and will not be able to get back into it because of laughter.